# Sorting an array of Objective-c objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting

So I have a custom class `Foo` that has a number of members:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSString *title;
    BOOL     taken;
    NSDate   *dateCreated;
}
```

And in another class I have an `NSMutableArray` containing a list of these objects. I would very much like to sort this array based on the `dateCreated` property; I understand I could write my own sorter for this (iterate the array and rearrange based on the date) but I was wondering if there was a proper Objective-C way of achieving this?

Some sort of sorting mechanism where I can provide the member variable to sort by would be great.

In C++ I used to overload the < = > operators and this allowed me to sort by object, but I have a funny feeling Objective-C might offer a nicer alternative?

Many thanks

Comment: In C++, you only need to overload `<`.

Comment: Have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's quite simple to do.

First, in your Foo object, create a method

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareWithAnotherFoo:(Foo*) anotherFoo;
```

Which will return

```
[[self dateCreated] compare:[anotherFoo dateCreated]];
```

In the end, call on the array

```
[yourArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareWithAnotherFoo:)];
```

Hope this helps,
Paul

Comment: Nice concise solution, though I had to change `compareWithDate` to `compare`.

Comment: @Pawel This works fine but with characters as å ä ö the sorting is a bit off. (å and ä appears after a and ö after o). You don't happen to know how to solve this?

Comment: @Filip the order you have described seems to be fine as å and ä are just versions of letter a with diacritic marks added. What exactly is the behaviour you would expect?

Comment: @Pawel Oh, sorry was in my own little swedish bubble, å ä ö appears after xyz in the swedish alphabet as ..xyzåäö. I managed to solve this using the following comparison method: - (NSComparisonResult) compareSongWithSong:(Song *)otherSong {
    return [[self title] compare:[otherSong title]
                         options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                           range:NSMakeRange(0, self.title.length)
                          locale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"sv_SE"]];
} Hope it helps someone!